# Canvas element inside jquery dialog ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to have HTML 5 canvas element inside jquery dialog ui. Nothing appears when the dialog is opened.
Thanks, sorry,I'm a noob at @ Jquery

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/SRZ9B/), it [is](http://jsfiddle.net/SRZ9B/1/). If these example don't solve your problem you'll have to show us some code and/or give more insights.

Comment: You are right it does work. The problem for some reason is when the external page I called used the load function didn't seem to execute the window.onload event. But using the jquery constructor..it displayed the canvas! Thanks!

Comment: Good that it works. Please provide your solution for other people with a similar question or mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks!